# How to setup alerting for the Dataform GCP integration?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dataform

For the Dataform Google Cloud Platform Integration, how (if possible in the first place) to setup notifications / alerting in case any action - and which action - in the workflow as scheduled via Google Cloud Scheduler fails, as such that an e-mail will be sent to me?

It seems I can setup alerting for the workflow execution itself via Audit logging based on the logs created ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/audit-logging)), however in this case I'm actually more interested in alerting for a failure **of any action** (and which action) inside a workflow which is scheduled with Google Cloud Scheduler.

See also [here](https://docs.dataform.co/dataform-web/scheduling/slack-notifications) about Dataform notifications in general (excl the GCP integration).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for errors during the Dataform workflow execution, you can create a log-based metric in Cloud Logging and monitor it on the Monitoring service, or directly create an alert based on these logs occurrences. The query for the logs could be something like this, I just filter by the service account that executes my Dataform workflow, and by severity=ERROR:

```
protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail="XXXX@gcp-sa-dataform.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
severity="ERROR"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, couldn't post this as a comment; it's not a proper answer to your question (which I have followed because I'm also interested in the same goal).

The closest we've come is to query the information_schema directly, i.e.

```
select 
    creation_time, 
    job_id, 
    statement_type, 
    query, 
    error_result.reason as error_reason,
    error_result.message as error_message,
    total_bytes_billed 
from `xxxx`.`region-xx`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS 
where user_email = "xxxx@gcp-sa-dataform.iam.gserviceaccount.com" 
and creation_time >= date_add(current_timestamp(),interval -7 day)
and error_result is not null 
order by creation_time desc
```

We poll this view and alert if rows appear.

Answer (score 0):

I utilised GCP Alerting policy to send notification to my work email and MS Team.
Here's the log query i used`resource.type="dataform.googleapis.com/Repository" resource.labels.repository_id="<your Dataform repo id>" severity=ERROR`

Answer (score 0):

We use log based alerts with the following template query:

```
resource.type="dataform.googleapis.com/Repository" 
jsonPayload.@type="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.dataform.logging.v1.WorkflowInvocationCompletionLogEntry" 
resource.labels.repository_id="repo-name"
jsonPayload.terminalState="FAILED" 
jsonPayload.releaseConfigId="production" 
jsonPayload.workflowConfigId="workflow-name"
```

This log based alert sends out messages on workflow failures. `jsonPayload.releaseConfigId` and `jsonPayload.workflowConfigId` allows us to specify release configs and workflow configs precisely.